# Using fetch in chrome extension doesn't include referer header in the request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api, referrer, http-referer

Normally, using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) from a website to send a request would include a referrer header in the request depending on the [referrer-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)

On a chrome extension background script, I have tried with referrer as client and referrerPolicy as unsafe-url, origin and origin-when-cross-origin.
In my manifest, I have my endpoint url in the permission but not all-urls.

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    referrer: 'client',
    referrerPolicy: 'origin',
    body: JSON.stringify({ params })
  })
```

Comment: Does it also happen in Firefox? Could be a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm haven't had a chance to try on Firefox yet.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Check your background page logs. When I attempt to set a referrer for ajax request there appears an error message: Refused to set unsafe header "Referer".

Answer (score 0):

A violent resolution:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
    details.requestHeaders.push({name: 'Referer', value:'http://localhost/referer'});
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
  },
  {urls: ["http://localhost/*"]},
  ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);


fetch('http://localhost/')
```

Comment: This is MV2-specific: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72736806/use-declarativenetrequest-to-set-the-referer-header-when-using-fetch-in-a-ch) for an MV3 answer.