# Use declarativeNetRequest to set the "Referer" header when using fetch() in a chrome extension (V3)

Tags: django-rest-framework, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api

Im working on a chrome extension using manifest V3. A core functionality of the extension is to enable users to send data from a website to the REST API of my django application, where the user is already logged in. While testing locally everything was fine, however when I went to test in staging, I found that with HTTPS django requires a "referer" in the POST header for CSRF protection.

From what I found chrome extensions just don't attach that header. So I tried the `declarativeNetRequest` API using the following code. However this only works when I open the URL in a tab. When fetch is called to post to the same URL, the rule is not matched. Is this the correct way to force a referer header when using fetch in V3? Thanks!

manifest.json:

```
...

"permissions": [
    ...
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"
  ],
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [{
      "id": "ruleset_1",
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "rules.json"
    }]
  },

...
```

rules.json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "requestHeaders": [
        {
          "header": "Referer",
          "operation": "set",
          "value": "whatever"
        }
      ]
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "https://api.myserver.com",
      "resourceTypes": [
        "main_frame"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

background.js:

```
...

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.onRuleMatchedDebug.addListener(function (m) {
  console.log('match:', m);
});

function post_data() {
    fetch(link, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token.value
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(text)
    })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error))

    return true;
}

...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to replace `main_frame` with `xmlhttprequest`, which is a type both for XHR and `fetch`.

Also, limit this rule to requests made by your extension. It can be done by specifying the extension's id in `domains`. Since the id may change during development, we'll set the rule dynamically.

1. Remove `declarative_net_request` from manifest.json.
2. Add the following code in background.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {
  const rules = [{
    id: 1,
    action: {
      type: 'modifyHeaders',
      requestHeaders: [{
        header: 'Referer',
        operation: 'set',
        value: 'whatever',
      }],
    },
    condition: {
      domains: [chrome.runtime.id],
      urlFilter: '|https://api.myserver.com/',
      resourceTypes: ['xmlhttprequest'],
    },
  }];
  await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: rules.map(r => r.id),
    addRules: rules,
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah,I completely overlooked the resourceTypes. It seems like you are out here single-handedly saving chrome extension devs from going insane. Thank you for all your helpful answers!

Comment: Saved my chops today. This is pretty much the only way to get API restrictions working with Google's APIs for extensions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent hours and days trying to find what's wrong.